# Android: Rotated view in popup window getting clipped

Tags: android, view, rotation, popup, popupwindow

I'm trying to rotate a `ListView` inside of a custom `popupWindow`. Below is my setup:

Here is the popup XML, `board_dialog.xml`:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/boardll"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/boardoptions"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:entries="@array/options_array_board" /> 
</RelativeLayout>
```

My custom `BoardPopup` class:

```
public class BoardPopup extends PopupWindow {
    private static final String TAG = BoardPopup.class.getSimpleName();    

    Context context;  
    RelativeLayout ll;
    ListView lv;

    private OnSubmitListener mListener;  

    public BoardPopup (Context ctx, OnSubmitListener listener) {  
        super(ctx);  

        context = ctx;  
        mListener = listener;  

        setContentView(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.board_dialog, null));  
        setHeight(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);  
        setWidth(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);  
        View popupView = getContentView();  
        setFocusable(true);  

        lv = (ListView) popupView.findViewById(R.id.boardoptions);
        ll = (RelativeLayout) popupView.findViewById(R.id.boardll);        
    }  

    public void show(View v) {        
        showAtLocation(v, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0); 
    }  

    public interface OnSubmitListener {  
        void valueChanged(String name, String number);  
    }

    public void fixDimensions() {
        getContentView().setBackgroundColor(Color.RED); //to highlight views
        ll.setRotation(90);
        update(292,630); //These numbers are not meant to be constant        
    }  
}
```

In my activity, showing the popup and I have to override `onWindowFocusChanged` in order to get post-drawn dimensions for the views inside the popup:

```
popup = new BoardPopup(c, MainGamePanel.this);
popupJustCreated = true;
popup.show(v);
```

.

```
@Override
 public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
      super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
      if (popup!=null && popupJustCreated) {
          popup.fixDimensions();
          popupJustCreated = false;
      }
 }
```

If I comment out `ll.setRotation(90);` and `update(292,630);` in `fixDimensions()` then everything looks normal:

[image]

If I add in the `ll.setRotation(90);`:

[image]

Finally, if I add in the `update(292,630);`:

[image]

In the final image, why does the layout not fill the popup? What view is that gray area? How can I get this to rotate and resize normally?

Some other things I've tried with no success:

- Using `LinearLayout` instead of `RelativeLayout`
- all different combinations of `wrap_content` and `match_parent`
- Doing basically the same thing with a custom `DialogFragment`

Comment: can you post a screenshot?

Comment: There's the before and after screenshots already posted in the OP. Here's the in between shot that I couldn't post: [Imgur](http://i.imgur.com/XVZfKX2l.png)

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue and just found a workaround. I was using the view rotationX property to rotate items within a RecyclerView and kept seeing strange clipping behaviour like the images above. What worked for me was calling setLayerType on the parent view (a RecyclerView in my case) with the following arguments:

```
view.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null)
```

The default layer type is is LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE for API >= 14). By the nature of this work around I'd say this is an Android bug.